# Configure security schemas and contexts in Springfox and Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, springfox

I have simple REST services implemented with Spring MVC. I decided to describe them with Springfox and Swagger 2.0. Everything seemed to be OK until I started adding security schemas and contexts. I use HTTP Basic authentication for certain endpoints and token-based authentication for others. Whatever I do, I cannot see any option to set HTTP Basic authentication credentials or to specify a token in Swagger UI. Below is my configuration. For simplicity's sake I apply both schemas to all endpoints here.

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {

    @Bean
    public Docket apiV1() {
      return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
        .select()
        .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
        .paths(PathSelectors.any())
        .build()
      .pathMapping("/api/v1")
      .securitySchemes(newArrayList(new BasicAuth("xBasic"), 
                                    new ApiKey("X-Auth-Token", "xAuthToken", "header")))
      .securityContexts(newArrayList(xBasicSecurityContext(), xAuthTokenSecurityContext()))
    }

    private SecurityContext xBasicSecurityContext() {
      SecurityContext.builder()
        .securityReferences(newArrayList(new SecurityReference("xBasic", 
                                                               new AuthorizationScope[0])))
        .build()
    }

    private SecurityContext xAuthTokenSecurityContext() {
      SecurityContext.builder()
        .securityReferences(newArrayList(new SecurityReference("xAuthToken", 
                                                               new AuthorizationScope[0])))
        .build()
    }
```

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31057343/adding-basic-authorization-for-swagger-ui

Comment: I would say that my problem is with Springfox configuration rather than hacking Swagger UI to support authentication with predefined credentials.

Comment: For enabling Basic Auth with Springfox annotation, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32384493/swagger-2-0-where-to-declare-basic-auth-schema

Answer (score 6):

I have tried this approach: to split Docket config. It forced me also to split API into two groups (and packages), but in the end it was a good architectural decision.

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {

    @Bean
    public Docket authTokenSecuredApi() {
      return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
        .groupName("authTokenGroup") // 2 Dockets -> need to differ using groupName
        .select()
        .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("cz.bank.controller.package1"))
        .paths(PathSelectors.any())
        .build()
        .securitySchemes(Collections.singletonList(new ApiKey("X-Auth-Token", 
                                                              "xAuthToken",
                                                              "header")))
        .securityContexts(Collections.singletonList(xAuthTokenSecurityContext()));
    }

    @Bean
    public Docket basicAuthSecuredApi() {
      return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
        .groupName("basicAuthGroup") // 2 Dockets -> need to differ using groupName
        .select()
        .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("cz.bank.controller.package2"))
        .paths(PathSelectors.any())
        .build()
        .securitySchemes(Collections.singletonList(new BasicAuth("xBasic")))
        .securityContexts(Collections.singletonList(xBasicSecurityContext()));
    }

    private SecurityContext xBasicSecurityContext() {
      return SecurityContext.builder()
        .securityReferences(Collections.singletonList(
                              new SecurityReference("xBasic", 
                                                    new AuthorizationScope[0])))
        .build();
    }

    private SecurityContext xAuthTokenSecurityContext() {
      return SecurityContext.builder()
        .securityReferences(Collections.singletonList(
                              new SecurityReference("xAuthToken", 
                                                    new AuthorizationScope[0])))
        .build();
    }
}
```

To tell the truth, I would prefer to configure authorization directly in controllers, using `authorizations` attribute of `@ApiOperation` or `@Api` Swagger annotations. But accorging to [this](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/2482) springfox "feature", it does not work on `@Api` annotation, which causes to copy it to every `@ApiOperation` that leads to untidy nasty ugly sinful code :-)

Comment: I have tried this but the swagger only displays endpoints filtered by the first Docket(in your case authTokenSecuredApi()). Is there anything else to be configured?

Comment: it always displays the latest docket group, nothing else